# Send form data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send all input in a form with ajax  .I have a form like this.

```
<form action="target.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="lname" />
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="buttom" name ="send" onclick="return f(this.form ,this.form.fname ,this.form.lname) " >
</form>
```

And in .js file we have following code :

```
function f (form ,fname ,lname ){
    att=form.attr("action") ;
    $.post(att ,{fname : fname , lname :lname}).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
    return true;
```

But this is not working.i don't want to use Form data .

Answer (score 31, accepted):

as far as we want to send all the form input fields which have name attribute, you can do this for all forms, regardless of the field names:

**First Solution**

```
function submitForm(form){
    var url = form.attr("action");
    var formData = {};
    $(form).find("input[name]").each(function (index, node) {
        formData[node.name] = node.value;
    });
    $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

**Second Solution**: in this solution you can create an array of input values:

```
function submitForm(form){
    var url = form.attr("action");
    var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
    $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Great! **First solution** works for Multi Dimensional arrays, like `... name="item[0][id]"` ! 
`.serialize()`, on the other hand - will not work for multi-dimensional arrays!

Comment: @Musa - How to control serialization of form elements in cases where there are a number of form fields but only a few need to be submitted. For example, there could be some pre-filled inputs like the document type or current date, which may need to be excluded from data.

Comment: @user12379095 you can disable the fields you don't want serialized

Answer (score 3):

In your function `form` is a DOM object, In order to use `attr()` you need to convert it to jQuery object.

```
function f(form, fname, lname) {
    action = $(form).attr("action");
    $.post(att, {fname : fname , lname :lname}).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    return true;
}
```

With [**.serialize()**](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
function f(form, fname, lname) {
    action = $(form).attr("action");
    $.post(att, $(form).serialize() ).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    return true;
}
```

Additionally, You can use [**.serialize()**](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "target.php",
  type: "post",
  data: "fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname,
}).done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Do we need to remove the 'target.php" from the action attribute then?

Answer (score 2):

I have written myself a function that converts most of the stuff one may want to send via AJAX to GET of POST query.
Following part of the function might be of interest:

```
  if(data.tagName!=null&&data.tagName.toUpperCase()=="FORM") {
    //Get all the input elements in form
    var elem = data.elements;
    //Loop through the element array
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      //Ignore elements that are not supposed to be sent
      if(elem[i].disabled!=null&&elem[i].disabled!=false||elem[i].type=="button"||elem[i].name==null||(elem[i].type=="checkbox"&&elem[i].checked==false))
        continue; 
      //Add & to any subsequent entries (that means every iteration except the first one) 
      if(data_string.length>0)
        data_string+="&";
      //Get data for selectbox
      if (elem[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == "SELECT")
      {
        data_string += elem[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value) ;
      }
      //Get data from checkbox
      else if(elem[i].type=="checkbox")
      {
        data_string += elem[i].name + "="+(elem[i].value==null?"on":elem[i].value);
      }
      //Get data from textfield
      else
      {
        data_string += elem[i].name + (elem[i].value!=""?"=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].value):"=");
      }
    }
    return data_string; 
  }
```

It does not need jQuery since I don't use it. But I'm sure jquery's `$.post` accepts string as seconf argument.

Here is the whole function, other parts are not commented though. I can't promise there are no bugs in it:

```
function ajax_create_request_string(data, recursion) {
  var data_string = '';
  //Zpracovani formulare
  if(data.tagName!=null&&data.tagName.toUpperCase()=="FORM") {
    //Get all the input elements in form
    var elem = data.elements;
    //Loop through the element array
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      //Ignore elements that are not supposed to be sent
      if(elem[i].disabled!=null&&elem[i].disabled!=false||elem[i].type=="button"||elem[i].name==null||(elem[i].type=="checkbox"&&elem[i].checked==false))
        continue; 
      //Add & to any subsequent entries (that means every iteration except the first one) 
      if(data_string.length>0)
        data_string+="&";
      //Get data for selectbox
      if (elem[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == "SELECT")
      {
        data_string += elem[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value) ;
      }
      //Get data from checkbox
      else if(elem[i].type=="checkbox")
      {
        data_string += elem[i].name + "="+(elem[i].value==null?"on":elem[i].value);
      }
      //Get data from textfield
      else
      {
        if(elem[i].className.indexOf("autoempty")!=-1) {
          data_string += elem[i].name+"=";
        }
        else
          data_string += elem[i].name + (elem[i].value!=""?"=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].value):"=");
      }
    }
    return data_string; 
  }
  //Loop through array
  if(data instanceof Array) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      if(data_string!="")
        data_string+="&";
      data_string+=recursion+"["+i+"]="+data[i];
    }
    return data_string;
  }
  //Loop through object (like foreach)
  for(var i in data) {
    if(data_string!="")
      data_string+="&";
    if(typeof data[i]=="object") {
      if(recursion==null)
        data_string+= ajax_create_request_string(data[i], i);
      else
        data_string+= ajax_create_request_string(data[i], recursion+"["+i+"]");
    }
    else if(recursion==null)
      data_string+=i+"="+data[i];
    else 
      data_string+=recursion+"["+i+"]="+data[i];
  }
  return data_string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted has two problems:

First: `<input type="buttom"` should be `<input type="button"...`.  This probably is just a typo but without `button` your input will be treated as `type="text"` as the default input type is `text`.

Second: In your `function f()` definition, you are using the `form` parameter thinking it's already a `jQuery` object by using `form.attr("action")`.  Then similarly in the `$.post` method call, you're passing `fname` and `lname` which are `HTMLInputElement`s.  I believe what you want is form's action url and input element's values.

Try with the following changes:

*HTML*

```
<form action="/echo/json/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="lname" />
    <input type="text" name="fname" />

    <!-- change "buttom" to "button" -->
    <input type="button" name="send" onclick="return f(this.form ,this.form.fname ,this.form.lname) " />
</form>
```

*JavaScript*

```
function f(form, fname, lname) {
    att = form.action; // Use form.action
    $.post(att, {
        fname: fname.value, // Use fname.value
        lname: lname.value // Use lname.value
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    return true;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d39f/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use serialize method of jquery to get form values. Try like this

```
<form action="target.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="lname" />
<input type="text" name="fname" />
<input type="buttom" name ="send" onclick="return f(this.form) " >
</form>

function f( form ){
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    att=form.attr("action") ;
    $.post(att, formData).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
function f (){
fname  = $("input[name='fname']").val();
lname  = $("input[name='fname']").val();
att=form.attr("action") ;
$.post(att ,{fname : fname , lname :lname}).done(function(data){
alert(data);
});
return true;
}
```