# How to Get the value of javascript variable in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new to JQuery so i have to ask this question. I have to get the value of undermentioned code into a php file.

```js
  jQuery(function($){

    var textover_api;

    // How easy is this??
  
    $('#target').TextOver({}, function() {
      textover_api = this;
  
    });
```

I want to get the text written by this code to the next php page. how can i do that. please help

Comment: You can use the ajax as well as traditional form processing etc. whatever convinient to you..

Comment: Either submit the form or use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Sending data from client to server using jQuery (Javascript) usually used to send without refreshing the whole page. 
This called [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

There are several sending methods to do it, the most popular are: POST & GET

A few examples:

[GET request with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

[POST request with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

[Sending form data using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662836/send-form-data-using-ajax)

[POST vs GET in AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715335/get-vs-post-in-ajax)

Write me if you need more explanation

Comment: Marina K. like the example given in this page https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/, i want to pass the form value to the next php page

Comment: @UsmanAhmedMani If you need to send data to _next php page_ then you can just use simple form - submit, where action of that form is your _next php page_  [simple form example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)