# Multiple arrays to a JSON array to PHP via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form

```
<form id="ajax-form" onsubmit="return false;">
<p class="legend">All fields marked with an asterisk are required.</p>

<fieldset>
    <legend>User Details</legend>
        <div><label for="post[uname]">Username <em>*</em></label> <input id="post[uname]" type="text" name="uname" value=""  /></div>
            <p class='note' id='err[Name]'></p>

</fieldset>

 <div class="buttonrow">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit This Form via AJAX" class="button" />  
    <input type="button" value="Start Again" class="button" />
     <a href="ajaxformval.html">Refresh this Page</a>
</div>

</form>
```

I have two arrays post and err. I'm trying to send them to php and then in php it will json_encode the array and print it on the screen like so:

```
{
   "err": {
       "uname": "Please enter a user name"
   }
   "post": {
       "uname": ""
    }
}
```

or this is if the user did enter a name:

```
{
   "post": {
       "uname": "Bob Ross"
    }
}
```

There could be multiple fields for post and err but it should still follow the same suite.

How do I send the data to php, I understand it's some sort of serializeArray but it doesn't format it properly when I do:

```
JSON.stringify($("#ajax-form").serializeArray())
```

A jsfiddle to full html:

https://jsfiddle.net/dzv8ttjn/1/

Comment: And what is your question....?

Comment: @DelightedD0D updated original post.

Comment: Is this the only input, or does your actual html have a bunch of inputs?

Comment: No theres two text fields, 2 radio buttons and 2 checkboxes. I just included uname as an example.

Comment: Can you post the full html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send form data using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662836/send-form-data-using-ajax)

Comment: Added @DelightedD0D

Comment: Looking at it now, one question, Is there some reason you are using jQuery 1.3.2? I ask because it's rather old and you'd be much better off with a newer version

Comment: It's just included in our starter file I can change it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to call `.serialize();` on the form which will give you something like: `user-name=some%20name&email=some%20emale&gender=Female&interests=Software`

Send that to the PHP script, and have the script create the format of the response while looping over the $_POST array. Something like the below would work:

(note that I've changed your id's to be more sensible and updated the jQuery version used)

```
<?php 
if(count($_POST)>0){
    $response = ['err'=>[], 'post'=>[]];
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        $response['post'][$key]=$value;
        if(trim($value) == '') $response['err'][$key]='Please enter a '.$key; 
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Lab4: Form Validation with AJAX,JQuery,JSON and PHP</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">


    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#ajax-form").on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var dataString = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              // url: "page.php", // add this line to send to some page other than the this one
              data: dataString,
              success: function(response) {
                if (response) {
                  alert('test worked');
                }
              },
              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr);
              }
            });

        });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

      <h2>Form Validation with AJAX,JQuery,JSON and PHP</h2>

      <div class="form-container">

        <span id="ajax-message"></span>

        <form id="ajax-form" onsubmit="return false;">
          <p class="legend">All fields marked with an asterisk are required.</p>

          <fieldset>
            <legend>User Details</legend>
            <div>
              <label for="uname">Username <em>*</em></label>
              <input id="uname" type="text" name="user-name" value="" />
              <p class='note' id='name-error'></p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="password">Email Address <em>*</em></label>
              <input id="password" type="text" name="email" value="" />
              <p class='note' id='password-error'></p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="post[gender]">Gender <em>*</em></label>
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" class="form-check-input" id="Male" required> Male
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" class="form-check-input" id="Female" required> Female
              <p class='note' id='gender-error'></p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="interests">Interests<em>*</em></label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="interests" value="Music" class="form-check-input" id="Music"> Music
              <input type="checkbox" name="interests" value="Software" class="form-check-input" id="Software"> Software
              <input type="checkbox" name="interests" value="Hardware" class="form-check-input" id="Hardware"> Hardware</div>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="buttonrow">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit This Form via AJAX" class="button" />
            <input type="button" value="Start Again" class="button" />
            <a href="ajaxformval.html">Refresh this Page</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <h3>JSON Array</h3>
      <pre id='debug'></pre>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```