# How to send the values of multiple created input fields on php via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, ajax

[image]

> I have there an example part of my form, (my form has 4 different fields/div like that) and i cannot think of how i can send the values of those created input fields on php via ajax. Sorry if i can't explain it well. I have searched for this but i can't get the exact answer i'm looking for.

```
<input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder="Knowledgeable/Proficient in.." name = "skills[]" >
```

> I want to use a function which uses some kind of name="skills[]" (or array type) instead of something like name="skills1". tyia!

Comment: I googled "send form data using ajax" and found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662836/send-form-data-using-ajax

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i checked it, but my problem is i have 4 divs that have multiple created input fields, i'm having problem on how to send it on ajax and fetch it on php. Thanks for answering!! :))

Answer (score 0):

If you give the skill inputs a class like so

```
<input type="text" class="form-control skill-input" placeholder="Knowledgeable/Proficient in..">
```

You can then create an object from your form in javascript (example using jquery)

```
var skills = [];
$(".skill-input").each(function() {
    skills.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(skills); //final array of skills

var resume = JSON.stringify({
    firstName: $('[name=firstName]').val(),
    lastname: $('[name=lastName]').val(),
    skills: skills
});

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: './submit.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {resume:resume}
});
```

then on your `submit.php` you can have

```
$form = json_decode($_POST['resume'], true);
echo $form['skills'];
```

Comment: how will i send those values with the other values from my form to my php page via ajax? thasnk you sir :))

Comment: updated my post.  Just got to my computer, so I will test the code.

Comment: @Prozky im sorry for the late reply, on  $form = json_decode($_POST['resume']); how can i get the value seperately? was it still like $_POST['firstName']; ? and how to get the value of the array skills? thank you so much!! this helps a lot :))

Comment: Hi @jes, I edited the bottom of my answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: thank you so much! will tell you if it worked! sorry for i am busy with finishing this project