# Wordpress Plugin Development admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Hello everyone I am trying to use ajax in my custom plugin for wordpress but got an issue in my console showing 400 bad request in admin-ajax

1. JS scripts

   ```
   public static function register_script(){

       wp_enqueue_script('ajaxscript', substr(plugin_dir_url(__FILE__), 0, -10) . '/assets/js/register-post.js', array( 'jquery', 'json2' ), '1.0.0', true );

       wp_localize_script( 'ajaxscript', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajaxnonce') ) );

   }
   ```

   2. Ajax

```js
function signup(){
  // alert("working");

  jQuery('#registration').on('submit', function(e) {
    var data =  jQuery("#registration").serialize();
    e.preventDefault();
    // e.stopPropagation(); // only neccessary if something above is listening to the (default-)event too

      jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
          processData: false,
          data: {
            action: 'register_ajax_request&nonce='+ my_ajax_object.nonce,
            data: data
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response) {
          if(response.success === true) {
               // jQuery("#vote_counter").html(response.vote_count)
            }else {
               // alert("Your vote could not be added")
            }
          }
          
        });   
      
    });
          
  }
```

3. Registration Function

```html
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_register_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');


function ajax_handle_request(){

 if (isset($_POST['register_trigger'])){

  $nonce = $_POST['nonce']; 
  print_r($nonce);
  exit();
 }
}
```

> Location of the registration.php is plugindirectory/inc/pages/. This is not a function.php like the wordpress theme.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try `data: {action: 'register_ajax_request', data: data, nonce: my_ajax_object.nonce}`

Comment: What Banzay said. The `action` parameter should only include the name of your action (`register_ajax_request`) and nothing else.

Comment: @Banzay it is still showing a bad 400

Comment: look at other section of console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9UfR.png - does form send any data?

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/zhfw5WW), [link](https://ibb.co/2WPNJHJ) @Banzay

Comment: my suggestion is to view value of data after `var data =  jQuery("#registration").serialize();` do `console.log(data);` Apparently script sends wrong data set

Comment: yes @Banzay it send data as seen in the link that i provided. but im not sure if the problem is the ajax action register_ajax_request if its sending it to  add_action('wp_ajax_register_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');

Comment: @Banzay i tried changing the code to this data: {'first_name':first_name} but it still giving me this

responseText: "0"
responseJSON: 0
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"

and in the header
action: register_ajax_request
data[first_name]: fdsfdsf
nonce: ca2f51d2c0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662836/send-form-data-using-ajax/21662926

Comment: @Banzay still 400

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just forgot to include a php file that the action is looking for.